# How to add sidecar container with git sync to wordpress helm deployment?

Tags: wordpress, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, bitnami, argocd

Im usign kubernetes helm Wordpress installation, Im managing everything using Argo CD. How to add sidecar container to this deployment?

I already have Wordpress installation, now that what I need is to sync wp-content with git repository because its only way to update files (bitnami wordpress is non-root container, I cant create sftp).

```
    apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  annotations:`enter code here`
    deployment.kubernetes.io/desired-replicas: '1'
    deployment.kubernetes.io/max-replicas: '2'
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: '2'
  creationTimestamp: '2021-08-03T07:52:20Z'
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: projectname
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: wordpress
    helm.sh/chart: wordpress-11.1.0
    pod-template-hash: 6f744b7944
  managedFields:
    - apiVersion: apps/v1
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        'f:metadata':
          'f:annotations':
            .: {}
            'f:deployment.kubernetes.io/desired-replicas': {}
            'f:deployment.kubernetes.io/max-replicas': {}
            'f:deployment.kubernetes.io/revision': {}
          'f:labels':
            .: {}
            'f:app.kubernetes.io/instance': {}
            'f:app.kubernetes.io/managed-by': {}
            'f:app.kubernetes.io/name': {}
            'f:helm.sh/chart': {}
            'f:pod-template-hash': {}
          'f:ownerReferences':
            .: {}
            'k:{"uid":"f1d0a1c2-6564-461e-8be4-2a80784c9d94"}':
              .: {}
              'f:apiVersion': {}
              'f:blockOwnerDeletion': {}
              'f:controller': {}
              'f:kind': {}
              'f:name': {}
              'f:uid': {}
        'f:spec':
          'f:replicas': {}
          'f:selector': {}
          'f:template':
            'f:metadata':
              'f:labels':
                .: {}
                'f:app.kubernetes.io/instance': {}
                'f:app.kubernetes.io/managed-by': {}
                'f:app.kubernetes.io/name': {}
                'f:helm.sh/chart': {}
                'f:pod-template-hash': {}
            'f:spec':
              'f:affinity':
                .: {}
                'f:podAntiAffinity':
                  .: {}
                  'f:preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution': {}
              'f:containers':
                'k:{"name":"wordpress"}':
                  .: {}
                  'f:env':
                    .: {}
                    'k:{"name":"ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:value': {}
                    'k:{"name":"MARIADB_HOST"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:value': {}
                    'k:{"name":"MARIADB_PORT_NUMBER"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:value': {}
                    'k:{"name":"WORDPRESS_AUTO_UPDATE_LEVEL"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:value': {}
                    'k:{"name":"WORDPRESS_BLOG_NAME"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:value': {}
                    'k:{"name":"WORDPRESS_DATABASE_NAME"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:value': {}
                    'k:{"name":"WORDPRESS_DATABASE_PASSWORD"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:valueFrom':
                        .: {}
                        'f:secretKeyRef':
                          .: {}
                          'f:key': {}
                          'f:name': {}
                    'k:{"name":"WORDPRESS_DATABASE_USER"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:value': {}
                    'k:{"name":"WORDPRESS_EMAIL"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:value': {}
                    'k:{"name":"WORDPRESS_ENABLE_HTACCESS_PERSISTENCE"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:value': {}
                    'k:{"name":"WORDPRESS_EXTRA_WP_CONFIG_CONTENT"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                    'k:{"name":"WORDPRESS_FIRST_NAME"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:value': {}
                    'k:{"name":"WORDPRESS_HTACCESS_OVERRIDE_NONE"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:value': {}
                    'k:{"name":"WORDPRESS_LAST_NAME"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:value': {}
                    'k:{"name":"WORDPRESS_PASSWORD"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:valueFrom':
                        .: {}
                        'f:secretKeyRef':
                          .: {}
                          'f:key': {}
                          'f:name': {}
                    'k:{"name":"WORDPRESS_PLUGINS"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:value': {}
                    'k:{"name":"WORDPRESS_SCHEME"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:value': {}
                    'k:{"name":"WORDPRESS_SKIP_BOOTSTRAP"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:value': {}
                    'k:{"name":"WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:value': {}
                    'k:{"name":"WORDPRESS_USERNAME"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:value': {}
                  'f:image': {}
                  'f:imagePullPolicy': {}
                  'f:livenessProbe':
                    .: {}
                    'f:failureThreshold': {}
                    'f:httpGet':
                      .: {}
                      'f:path': {}
                      'f:port': {}
                      'f:scheme': {}
                    'f:initialDelaySeconds': {}
                    'f:periodSeconds': {}
                    'f:successThreshold': {}
                    'f:timeoutSeconds': {}
                  'f:name': {}
                  'f:ports':
                    .: {}
                    'k:{"containerPort":8080,"protocol":"TCP"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:containerPort': {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:protocol': {}
                    'k:{"containerPort":8443,"protocol":"TCP"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:containerPort': {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:protocol': {}
                  'f:readinessProbe':
                    .: {}
                    'f:failureThreshold': {}
                    'f:httpGet':
                      .: {}
                      'f:path': {}
                      'f:port': {}
                      'f:scheme': {}
                    'f:initialDelaySeconds': {}
                    'f:periodSeconds': {}
                    'f:successThreshold': {}
                    'f:timeoutSeconds': {}
                  'f:resources':
                    .: {}
                    'f:requests':
                      .: {}
                      'f:cpu': {}
                      'f:memory': {}
                  'f:securityContext':
                    .: {}
                    'f:runAsNonRoot': {}
                    'f:runAsUser': {}
                  'f:terminationMessagePath': {}
                  'f:terminationMessagePolicy': {}
                  'f:volumeMounts':
                    .: {}
                    'k:{"mountPath":"/bitnami/wordpress"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:mountPath': {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:subPath': {}
              'f:dnsPolicy': {}
              'f:hostAliases':
                .: {}
                'k:{"ip":"127.0.0.1"}':
                  .: {}
                  'f:hostnames': {}
                  'f:ip': {}
              'f:restartPolicy': {}
              'f:schedulerName': {}
              'f:securityContext':
                .: {}
                'f:fsGroup': {}
              'f:serviceAccount': {}
              'f:serviceAccountName': {}
              'f:terminationGracePeriodSeconds': {}
              'f:volumes':
                .: {}
                'k:{"name":"wordpress-data"}':
                  .: {}
                  'f:name': {}
                  'f:persistentVolumeClaim':
                    .: {}
                    'f:claimName': {}
        'f:status':
          'f:availableReplicas': {}
          'f:fullyLabeledReplicas': {}
          'f:observedGeneration': {}
          'f:readyReplicas': {}
          'f:replicas': {}
      manager: kube-controller-manager
      operation: Update
      time: '2021-08-03T08:13:55Z'
  name: projectname-wordpress-6f744b7944
  namespace: projectname
  ownerReferences:
    - apiVersion: apps/v1
      blockOwnerDeletion: true
      controller: true
      kind: Deployment
      name: projectname-wordpress
      uid: f1d0a1c2-6564-461e-8be4-2a80784c9d94
  resourceVersion: '4592350732'
  uid: 38b63e07-3845-4057-9476-62229f84621e
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: projectname
      app.kubernetes.io/name: wordpress
      pod-template-hash: 6f744b7944
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: projectname
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
        app.kubernetes.io/name: wordpress
        helm.sh/chart: wordpress-11.1.0
        pod-template-hash: 6f744b7944
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - podAffinityTerm:
                labelSelector:
                  matchLabels:
                    app.kubernetes.io/instance: projectname
                    app.kubernetes.io/name: wordpress
                namespaces:
                  - projectname
                topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
              weight: 1
      containers:
        - env:
            - name: ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
              value: 'yes'
            - name: MARIADB_HOST
              value: projectname-mariadb
            - name: MARIADB_PORT_NUMBER
              value: '3306'
            - name: WORDPRESS_DATABASE_NAME
              value: bitnami_wordpress
            - name: WORDPRESS_DATABASE_USER
              value: bn_wordpress
            - name: WORDPRESS_DATABASE_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: mariadb-password
                  name: projectname-mariadb
            - name: WORDPRESS_USERNAME
              value: user
            - name: WORDPRESS_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: wordpress-password
                  name: projectname-wordpress
            - name: WORDPRESS_EMAIL
              value: user@example.com
            - name: WORDPRESS_FIRST_NAME
              value: FirstName
            - name: WORDPRESS_LAST_NAME
              value: LastName
            - name: WORDPRESS_HTACCESS_OVERRIDE_NONE
              value: 'no'
            - name: WORDPRESS_ENABLE_HTACCESS_PERSISTENCE
              value: 'no'
            - name: WORDPRESS_BLOG_NAME
              value: User's Blog!
            - name: WORDPRESS_SKIP_BOOTSTRAP
              value: 'no'
            - name: WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX
              value: wp_
            - name: WORDPRESS_SCHEME
              value: http
            - name: WORDPRESS_EXTRA_WP_CONFIG_CONTENT
            - name: WORDPRESS_AUTO_UPDATE_LEVEL
              value: none
            - name: WORDPRESS_PLUGINS
              value: none
          image: 'docker.io/bitnami/wordpress:5.7.2-debian-10-r29'
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          livenessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 6
            httpGet:
              path: /wp-admin/install.php
              port: http
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 120
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 5
          name: wordpress
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              name: http
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 8443
              name: https
              protocol: TCP
          readinessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 6
            httpGet:
              path: /wp-login.php
              port: http
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 5
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 300m
              memory: 512Mi
          securityContext:
            runAsNonRoot: true
            runAsUser: 1001
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /bitnami/wordpress
              name: wordpress-data
              subPath: wordpress
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      hostAliases:
        - hostnames:
            - status.localhost
          ip: 127.0.0.1
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1001
      serviceAccount: default
      serviceAccountName: default
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
        - name: wordpress-data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: projectname-wordpress
status:
  availableReplicas: 1
  fullyLabeledReplicas: 1
  observedGeneration: 1
  readyReplicas: 1
  replicas: 1
```

Somebody suggested to add this:

```
sidecars:
  - name: git-sync
    image: bitnami/git:2.32.0-debian-10-r24
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    command:
      - /bin/bash
      - -ec
      - |
        [[ -f "/opt/bitnami/scripts/git/entrypoint.sh" ]] && source "/opt/bitnami/scripts/git/entrypoint.sh"
        while true; do
            #Add here your commands to synchronize the git repository with /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content
            sleep 60
        done
    volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /bitnami/wordpress
        name: wordpress-data
        subPath: Wordpress
```

But Im trying and Im not sure Im doing good.

Comment: That yaml that was suggested needs to be added to your `values.yml` if you are using the Bitnami chart (which I assume you are because you mention Bitnami in your message). That will add an extra container to the pods in the WordPress deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `ReplicaSet` manifest, `containers` is a list. You can add sidecars by adding more containers to that list.

Since you're trying to sync some static assets, you might find that an [init container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) is the better choice, since it'll complete before your main container starts.